# Magento 2.4.5 cannot remove container

Tags: magento, magento2

I cannot remove container "header.panel.wrapper" specifically in my custom theme in magento 2.4.5.

If I add the line `<referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>` in the file from luma theme: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml, it removes. But if I create this file in my custome theme: app/design/frontend/Singree/walkbeyond/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml, with the same content as the luma-theme file, it just won't remove.
This is the code of file Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml from my custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you search for header.panel.wrapper you see its not a block, but it is defined as a container. So try and use:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true"/>
```

That should work in your custom theme.